# Non clickable icons in a div within a div

Tags: css, html, z-index

Any ideas how to get the social icons clickable? I know if I remove the main #artistheader the icons become clickable, however that #artistheader has the header BG image.

```
<!--Begin Artist Header-->
<div id="artistheader">
  <div id="artistimage"><img src="../images/ykmfull.png" alt="YKM"></div>
  <div id="artistname"><center><img src="../images/ykmName.png" alt="YKM"></center></div>
  <div id="artistSocial"><center>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/YoungKingsCompany" target="_blank"><img src="../images/fb.png" alt="fb" width="50" border="0"></a><a href="http://www.twitter.com/youngkingsmula" target="_blank"><img src="../images/twitter.png" alt="tw" width="50"></a><img src="../images/insta.png" alt="insta" width="50"></center></div>
<!--artist header end--></div>
```

I added the relative positioning and z-indexes trying to find a solution weren't originally there.

```
#artistheader {
   position: relative;
   z-index: -45;
   clear: both;
   float: left;
   margin-left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   display: block;
}

#artistimage {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 8.4249%;
  width: 24.1758%;
  display: block;
}
#artistname {
  clear: none;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 9.5238%;
  width: 41.0256%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 7%;
}
#artistSocial {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5000;
  clear: none;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 9.5238%;
  width: 41.0256%;
  display: block;
}
#fb {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5000;
  clear: none;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 26.3736%;
  width: 32.6007%;
  display: block;
}
#tw {
  clear: none;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1.0989%;
  width: 15.7509%;
  display: block;
}
#insta {
  clear: none;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1.0989%;
  width: 15.7509%;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: what you have tried? prepare fiddle from http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Seems to work fine in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4dCAV/

Comment: So, I figured it out. When writing up the Jfiddle I noticed in the #artistheader the background image wasn't in the code... (there's a duplicate somewhere). Low and behold in the page's source code is another #artistheader css rule. Upon removing the rule in the css and previewing the problem has been fixed. No idea how two different #artistheader tags got inserted.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt responses guys. You guys are so talented just talking to you empowers me to fix the problem lol

Comment: @BDSmith Put your solution as an answer and accept it :)

Comment: Gotcha I have to wait so long to answer my own question then wait even longer after that to accept lol Newbie on this site my rep isn't high.

Answer (score 0):

Double instances of #artistheader existed. 1 in the source code on the page and 1 in the CSS. Upon deleting the rule on the CSS and leaving the one in the source code  the links worked again. Not sure where the second instance came (one in source code) and I'm it didn't matter which I left but because I have blur effects on the one in source code I kept it. I assume both were conflicting with each other and then just "froze" that section.